# Remove File Extension and URL Variable using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making up myself a small blog and I found a useful .htaccess file to remove file extensions:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php
```

This works just fine and all pages are showing up .php less. I know wanted to extend this so when I click a link to a specific blog post (say /blog/index.php?art=1) it just shows in the url as website/blog/1. I thought to tag on to the end of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/index.php?art=$0 [L]
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. EDIT Actually it breaks the blog page so no snippets are pulled through from the DB

My .htaccess file is in the root directory and the blog files are /root/blog/index.php

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: Does `/blog/` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: No, it's all in the root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike most other languages, the parameters in `.htaccess` are **not** 0-based. To access the first parameter, you should use `$1`, not `$0`.

The following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/index.php?art=$1 [L]
```

It might also be worthwhile to add some tests in there, for example you might only want numerical values passed to `art`, so you can improve it using:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog/index.php?art=$1 [L]
```

Also, it might be worthwhile to add the `QSA` flag, since this will also preserve any query string that is passed in the original URL:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog/index.php?art=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @benm Would the link be the same as I have it (index.php?art=1) or should I change it to something else?

Comment: You can change the link to `/blog/1`.

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks, but now it's broken my index.php page. I use a simple php script to pull the blog info from the db and display a snippet of each blog, but now nothing comes through

Comment: That's a separate question. Please ask it on SO as such.

Comment: Ok, will do (wasn't sure if they were linked). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem. When you ask the other question, be sure to include as much info as possible (including code samples).